# Apache web server not starting

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp

I have just bought a new MacBook and I am migrating over from Windows.  I want to set up a PHP environment and started to follow the instructions here: [Installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Mac OS X Sierra](https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-sierra/)

But, being new to all this, I got as far as

Uncomment the following line (remove #): LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

After that I couldn't do anything else.

So, I downloaded XAMPP and tried to install everything that way.  MySQL is running fine but Apache Web Server will not start and I think I must have done something wrong earlier to cause this.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this to make it run?

Thanks.

Comment: No way for us to tell what is the issue if you yourself claim that it might be "something" you did wrong earlier. Remember that we cannot look over your shoulder. So you have to tackle the issue in a constructive way: _post the exact error message you get when trying to start the http server_. Something like "will not start" does not help here.

Comment: I did everything up to the point I mentioned above.  So now, when I try to start Apache I get: Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started but when.I check, it says stopped.

Comment: Take a look at your http servers error log file. That is where you can usually read what the actual issue is it ran into.

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance use Skype? I am not too sure if this problem still exists, but in the past Skype used Port 80 and by doing that, it blocked the Apache. You can change the Port in your Skype settings.